# PHP & jQuery file upload issues

Tags: php, jquery, upload, is-uploaded-file

I'm trying to use [blueimp's jQuery file upload script](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload).

The files are sent to "upload.php":

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    // Set variables
    $file_name  = stripslashes($file['name']);

    if (!is_uploaded_file($file['name'])) {
        echo '{"name":"'.$file_name.' is not a uploaded file."}';
        exit;
    }
}
```

.. but the script fails at is_uploaded_file despite passing isset($_FILES['file']).

What may be causing this?

**EDIT:**

I changed from `$file['name']` to `$file['tmp_name']` and the `is_uploaded_file` is passed. Now the script fails at `move_uploaded_file`:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file_name, $upload_dir."/".$file_name)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($_FILES['file']);` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])`. This is the actual filename on the server.

`$file['name']` is the filename on the client's computer, which is only handy for renaming the file *after* it was uploaded.

For more information, read the docs on [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file):

> For proper working, the function
>   is_uploaded_file() needs an argument
>   like $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],
>   - the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine
>   $_FILES['userfile']['name'] does not
>   work

Additionally, you said `move_uploaded_file()` is not working as well. As expected, this is caused by the **exact same problem**:

You are trying to move the file `$file_name`, but `$file_name` is set to `$file['name']` and not `$file['tmp_name']`. Please understand that `$file['name']` contains only a string that equals the **original filename** on the computer, while `$file['tmp_name']` contains a string pointing to a path on the server where the filename is not temporarily stored.

Comment: This worked! However, the script now fails at move_uploaded_file. I'll update the question. Hang on...

Comment: @Orolin before you do, be sure this is not the *exact* same problem :)

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right. Thanks for pointing this out Aron :) I was totally confused about the difference between $file['name'] and $file['tmp_name'].